# Deep "npm update"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Running `npm update` updates items listed in package.json; however, the dependencies of those items are still outdated.

The obvious workaround is to run `npm update` once more. Sometimes I need to run it 3+ times to have clean `npm outdated`. Is there a flag in `npm update` to perform a deep update?

Another extreme workaround is to reinstall

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

**Update**

It has bee 5 years, and I am still running the code above with the addition of `rm package-lock.json` when I really need to shake it. Seeing "red lines" in `npm out` output after `npm up` is no longer a problem.

Comment: aren't depends supposed to be old copies that the needy code can concretely handle?

Comment: be careful, your packages may be incompatible with newer versions of their dependencies.. i think it's a bad idea to do that

Comment: @meriadec: yeah, but you can get away with it 9/10 times...  ;)

Comment: The main point is not to have any "red" lines in `npm outdated` command.

Comment: historical note: npm used to behave exactly as you desire, but they updated it to allow locking-in specific versions of depends to avoid an update breaking expectations... i think that was around 2010/11, not sure which version.

Comment: @kornieff, it's so interesting. Can you show steps to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As an *ugly workaround* I have this function defined in my ~/.bash_profile

```
function up {
    npm remove --save "$1";
    npm install --save "$1";
}
```

So whenever I want to update a dependency I just run `up express` or `up yourFavoritePackage`

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the directory structure in node_modules you will notice that each module has its own subdir node_modules for its dependencies. You shouldn't need to run "npm update" more than once.

Comment: I agree, in theory, yes; however, in real world, if you run `npm outdated` after `npm update`, you will see that this is not so.